# Comma questions

Tags: commas

Using commas in English has always been difficult for me as a non-native speaker, as in high school no attention whatsoever was given to that. Because of this, I have a couple of sentences where I do not know whether the commas are correct or not. I'd be quite happy if you could help me on that:

1. Thus**,** flexible devices**,** like dishwashers or electric water heaters,
   can provide significant flexibility to the system.
2. e.g.**,** Germany, France**,** and Italy
3. In Europe as a whole**,** nuclear energy was the main source  for generating
   electricity**,** having  contributed to 25 % of the whole generation.
4. While in the current system**,**  the supply follows the demand**,** in
   future**,** the demand has to follow the power supply.
5. Fossil fuels mainly generated the energy for buildings**,** whereas 
   renewable energy accounted for only 18 %.

Update: Thanks for all the answers so far. Can anyone tell me something about sentence 3. , 4. and 5. The answers given so far for these sentences are not satisfactory for me. I'd appreciate every input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for sentence 3, here is my suggestion:

3. [Throughout the whole of Europe], nuclear energy was the main source for generating electricity, having contributed to 25% of the [generated energy supply].
   (Note: my personal edits are in the brackets.) You would not wish to say "generation" at the end, because that word is much more frequently used by English speakers to refer to an age range of people (as in *Generation X*) or the grandfather-to-father-to-grandson type of "generation."

Okay, if you wish to say that nuclear energy was NOT the main source for all of Europe, here's what I would recommend:

"Nuclear energy was not the main source for generating electricity in all of Europe, having contributed to only 25% of the total generated energy supply."

Comment: Thanks Naomi for your answer. I have a question regarding 'Throughout the whole of Europe': What I want to say is that for Europe in total nuclear energy was the source NOT for every single country in Europe. For example in Germany (which is obviously part of Europe) nuclear energy was not the main source for generating electricity. So would you rather use the term 'For Europe as a whole' to say this?

Comment: I edited my answer to try and answer this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Naomi. Basically what I do I compare the energy mix in Europe (as a whole) and Germany (which is part of Europe). I would like to say that nuclear energy was the main source for electrcitiy generation for Europe (as a whole). If I just write Europe, it think this might be misleading because Germany is a part of Europe. But I do want to compare them.

Comment: I think you would want to say something like: "For Europe as a whole, nuclear energy was the main source of energy..., however, in Germany,...." Use however to set up a contrast.

Comment: Thanks Naomi for your answer. Do I have to write 'For Europe as as whole, nuclear energy...' or  'In Europe as a whole, nuclear energy ...'?

Comment: Either one will work I think

Comment: Thanks Naomi for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

1 is correct, “*thus*” is what is known as a fronting adverb – these are followed by a comma. But the commas at “*, like dishwashers or electric water heaters,* are parenthetical commas because they separate an example from the main clause. The main clause is “*Thus, flexible devices can provide significant flexibility to the system.*"

2 This comma is the “**Oxford comma**”: it is useful but not always necessary or correct. It is used in a list of separate items.

3 “*In entire Europe*” is not idiomatic. “*Throughout the whole of Europe*” is correct. Like 1., it is a fronting adverbial (phrase).

4 *While in the current system,* and “*in future,*" are also fronting adverbials.

5 seems to be missing a verb

Comment: Thanks a lot Greybeard for your answer. So in 1) would you use a comma before 'like'? This is a general quesiton with regard to 'like A, B or C'? Should there be a comma BEFORE hte ',like'? And in 5) there is no verb missing. I just wanted to know if I need a comma before 'whereas'?

Comment: 5 Could be improved thusly: "Fossil fuels generated most of the electricity for the buildings, while renewable energy accounted for only 18%."

Comment: Thanks RobJarvis for your answer. Do I have to use a comma after 'like' and 'whereas'?

Comment: @PeterBe "*Do I have to use a comma after 'like' and 'whereas'?*" I have given the example for "like". The word "whereas" does not seem to appear in your question and this seems to be a new question for which you have given no context.

Comment: Hi all its me again. I have to admit that I do not understand the answer of Greybeard regarding the point 4) "While in the current system**,** the supply follows the demand**,** in future**,**..." Do I need the commas before and after 'in future'?

Comment: And what about the second comma in 3) "**,** having contributed to 25 % of the whole generation"

Comment: @PeterBe *1 is correct, “thus” is what is known as a fronting adverb – these are followed by a comma.* - *4 While in the current system, and “in future," are also fronting adverbials.* -- What do you not understand?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greybeard. The sentence is different:"While in the current system**,** the supply follows the demand**,** in future**,** the demand has to follow the power supply." There is no 'and' in this sentence because it would not fit. So my question is basically about the possible commas before and after 'in future' (without 'and'). Further, as stated before, point 3) is not clear regarding the second comma before 'having'

Comment: *The sentence is different* but the grammatical principle is not.

Comment: Thanks Greybeard for your comment. I still do not know whether I should put commas in ", in future," and before  ',having'

Comment: I would omit the "while" and punctuate thus - note the semicolon: ***In the current system, the supply follows the demand; in future, the demand has to follow the power supply.***

Comment: Thanks for your comment Greybeard. What if I want to use the 'while'. Would I need a comma before it? This is a general question, so it is not restricted to this specific sentence.

Comment: *What if I want to use the 'while'?* You don't want to use "while".

Comment: Thanks Greybeard for your comment. In fact, I do want to use 'while' or let's say it like this: I don't like your sentence with the semicolon. So for me the question has still not been answered. Do I need commas before and after 'in future' (see full sentence in the original post)